# JS: Live search not working with spaces between two query

Tags: javascript, search

performing this search operation on JSON data, it works show filter data when enter term in search bar but it works only with one term as soon as I add space and other term it shows nothing, what am I doing wrong? Also it takes time to filter data around 14000 records are in JSON file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#selectterm').change(function() {
            var sterm = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/fee/get/" + sterm,
                success: function(res) {
                    if (res) {
                        $('#txt-search').keyup(function() {
                            var searchField = $(this).val();
                            if (searchField === '') {
                                $('#filter-records').html('');
                                return;
                            }
                            var output = '<div class="row">';
                            var count = 1;
                            $.each(res, function(key, lol) {
                                if ((lol.strm.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchField.toLowerCase()) != -1) ||
                                    (lol.subject_cd.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchField.toLowerCase())  != -1) ||
                                    (lol.catalog_nbr.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchField.toLowerCase())  != -1)) {
                                    output += '<table class="table">';
                                    output += '<thead>';
                                    output += '<tr>';
                                    output += '<th scope="col">Term</th>';
                                    output += '<th scope="col">Subject</th>';
                                    output += '<th scope="col">Catlog Nbr</th>';
                                    output += '</tr>';
                                    output += '</thead>';
                                    output += '<tbody>';
                                    output += '<tr>';
                                    output += '<td>' + lol.strm + '</td>';
                                    output += '<td>' + lol.subject_cd + '</td>';
                                    output += '<td>' + lol.catalog_nbr + '</td>';
                                    output += '</tr>';
                                    output += '</tbody>';
                                    output += '</table>';
                                    if (count % 2 == 0) {
                                        output += '</div><div class="row">'
                                    }
                                    count++;
                                }
                            });
                            output += '</div>';
                            $('#filter-records').html(output);
                        });
                    } 
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: so you expect `foo bar` to match something like `foo pickle bar`??? Or are you saying it is not matching a string `foo bar awesome`. IndexOf is NOT going to be looking for two words, it is only matching the string....

Comment: it works only with `foo` as soon you put space its stop filtering

Comment: So do you have a string with `foo[space]` ?

Comment: kind of for example COMM 727, it works with COMM but when I enter COMM [SPACE] 727, it stop filtering

Comment: @epascarello referring to your updated first comment, I need it to match `foo bar awesome` from entire JSON data and show all the results with match with whatever is there in search bar

Comment: Okay so you need to debug it and figure out why. Impossible for us to figure out why.... In the loop do something like `if (lol.strm.toLowerCase().indexOf('comm`)) { console.log(lol.strm.toLowerCase())}` and see what the value is.... And you can encode `escape(lol.strm.toLowerCase())` and see if the space is a space and not some other unicode.